# checking whether turing machine passes at least k>2 states before accepting a word

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem

$L=\{\langle M,k\rangle \mid\exists w\in L(M) \text{ such that $M$ passes at least 
 $k>2$ distinct states before accepting $w$}\}$

I try to think of reduction to prove that this language is neither RE nor coRE.
How to approach this problem? Is there a hint, or intuition?

I usually check whether Rice can be used, but the question here is not about the language itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $L$ is acceptable (just simulate $M$ and keep track of the number of distinct states encountered during the simulation). We now show that it is not decidable.

If $L$ were decidable, you would be able to solve the Halting problem as follows:
given a TM $T$ and an input $x \in \Sigma^*$, construct a TM $M$ that ignores its input, simulates $T$ with input $x$ and, when the simulation is complete, accepts.
You can further ensure that, if $M$ accepts, then it also traverses at least $3$ distinct states by just transitioning from the initial state to another (distinct) state before starting the simulation of $T$.

Now check whether $\langle M, 3 \rangle \in L$. If the answer is affirmative, then there is some $w \in \Sigma^*$ for which $M(w)$ accepts, showing that $T(x)$ halts.
If the answer is negative then $M$ never halts, showing that $T(x)$ does not halt.

Comment: How can I ensure that M visits at least three states before accepting? It doesn't depend on T?
Or do I have to build M so that I add 3 states, first going through them without changing anything, and then running T?

Comment: Just build $M$ so that it goes form its initial state to another state, and then simulates $T$. This is already ensures that $M$ traverses at least $2$ distinct states. When (if) the simulation of $T$ completes, $M$ will move to the accepting state. Therefore if $T$ halts,  $M$ visits at least $3$ distinct states.

Comment: got it. thank you very much!